# First time adhoc app load onto iPhone

Tags: iphone, latency, adhoc

Hey I've got an adhoc distribution of an app I'm attempting to put on the clients phone. On the initial load after sync to our test phones with iTunes I'm seeing a 30 second load time until the app shows the main screen. Every subsequent load, however, is lightning fast.

I was just wondering if the first load from an adhoc distribution is going to see some more latency or maybe I'm just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about, but presumably the very first load from iTunes involves:

1) installing your ad hoc provisioning profile on the device
2) installing your app on the device 
3) a full suite of tests to make sure the application matches your ad hoc provisioning profile

Instead, subsequent loads (updates) do not require installing again your ad hoc provisioning profile on the device since it's already there, and probably less tests to check for the profile matching or not. Finally, being updates, the OS does not remove many directories already available, including the Documents directory etc.

This may explain the difference you are experiencing.